# Problem accessing Internet in 4.0 ICS

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, wi-fi, networking, dhcp, dns

For some strange reason, my Android 4.0 ICS tablet is no longer able to access the Internet.
First, via wifi, it could'n connect to two distinct networks.
Then later, I tried to connect it to home router via dhcp.  It could not.
As for wifi, the tablet gets an IP number.

I don't know how this happened, if it is a `route` problem or a dns problem or other.
Tried to install a terminal to check a `route` command, but it is not available (at least to me).
So I ask what can I do to solve this issue?  Restore original configuration?  Other?

Answer (score 2):

ICS has issues on some devices with Wireless-N. My Acer A500 works properly, but my 2 Xperia phones kill my router instantly if I use the N-draft protocol.

So, try deactivating N-draft mode in your Android device or your router, then it sohuld work.